# Suitable non-countable union of sets with measure zero is still a set of measure zero?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples, geometric-measure-theory

Let $R=[0,a]\times [0,b]$ be a rectangle in $\Bbb{R}^2$. Associated to each $t\in [0,a]$ we have a set $E_t\subset [0,b]\subset \Bbb{R}$ which has **measure zero** *(it is worth to remark that here we are considering the Borel measure of the real line, or "length", if we want)*. Set $\mathscr{E}_t=\{t\}\times E_t\subset R\subset \Bbb{R}^2$. So, my question is: still has the set

$$\bigcup\limits_{t\in [0,a]}\mathscr{E}_t\subset R\subset \Bbb{R}^2 $$

measure zero? *(considering now the measure of the plane, or "area")*.

[image]

If this is true, is there some theorem or result that garantees it easily? If this is false, which is the counterexample?

THANK YOU, GUYS!

Comment: Do you mean to assume that the union is measurable at all?

Comment: @bof What do you mean? $E_t$ and $\mathscr{E}_t$ have the same cardinality... Does this help?

Comment: @EricWofsey: I don't know (even) if the union is measurable.

Comment: @EricWofsey take a look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914263/f-acl-implies-exists-nabla-f-almost-everywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us denote your set by $E$, Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mu_1$, and Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $\mu_2$.  If $E$ is measurable, then by Fubini's theorem applied to the characteristic function of $E$, $$\mu_2(E)=\int_{[0,a]}\mu_1(E_t)dt=0.$$  More generally, this shows that the inner measure of $E$ is always $0$, by applying this argument to any measurable subset of $E$.

However, $E$ need not be measurable.  In fact, it is possible to choose sets $E_t$ such that each one has at most one point, but the outer measure of $E$ is $ab$, the measure of the entire rectangle.  You can prove this by transfinite induction: there are only $\mathfrak{c}$ different Borel subsets of $[0,a]\times[0,b]$ of positive measure and each of them intersect $\{t\}\times[0,b]$ for $\mathfrak{c}$ different values of $t$, and so by an induction of length $\mathfrak{c}$ you can choose at most one point from each $\{t\}\times[0,b]$ and get a set that intersects every such Borel set.

Answer (score 2):

If $E=\bigcup_t \mathcal E_t$ is measurable, then the answer is yes, directly by Fubini's theorem. In general, (assuming axiom of choice) it is not true, by a construction similar to that of the Bernstein set.

Let $(F_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak c}$ be an enumeration of all closed subsets of $R$ of positive measure. By easy transfinite induction you can construct a sequence $(t_\alpha,s_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak c}$ such that $(t_\alpha,s_\alpha)\in F_\alpha$, and such that for $\alpha\neq \beta$ we have $t_\alpha\neq t_\beta$ (this can be done because the projection of a closed set of positive measure onto one axis will always have size continuum -- for example by Fubini).

Then put $E_t=\{s_\alpha\}$ if $t=t_\alpha$ and $E_t=\emptyset$ if for no $\alpha$ we have $t=t_\alpha$. Clearly, each $E_t$ is null, but $\bigcup_t \mathcal{E}_t$ has full outer measure: indeed, by construction it intersects every closed set of positive measure, which -- as you can easily check -- is equivalent to having full outer measure.

Comment: Take a look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914263/f-acl-implies-exists-nabla-f-almost-everywhere