# $f$ ACL $\implies \exists \nabla f$ almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, continuity, lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere

We have the following definition for an absolutely continuous function:

> **Definition (absolutely continuous):** A function $f:I\to \mathbb{R}^n$, $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ interval, is said to be absolutely continuous if, $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$ such that,$$[x_k,y_k]\subset I, k\in \{1,\dots,n\}\text{ pairwise disjoint intervals with }\sum_{k=1}^n|y_k-x_k|<\delta$$ $$\implies\sum_{k=1}^n|f(y_k)-f(x_k)|<\epsilon.$$

And then, we have the following proposition

> **Proposition 1:** If $f:I\longrightarrow\Bbb{R}^n$ is absolutely continuous, then $f$ is differentiable at almost everywhere in $I$.

Ok, now we give the definition of a *absolutely continuous on lines (ACL)* function.

> **Definition (ACL):** Let $\Omega\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ be a domain (open connected set) and $F:\Omega\longrightarrow \Bbb{R}^m$ a function. Given a $n$-dimensional parallelepiped $P=[a_1,b_1]\times \dots \times [a_n,b_n]\subset \Omega$ and given a choice of $n-1$ fixed values $x_1\in [a_1,b_1],\dots,x_{i-1}\in[a_{i-1},b_{i-1}],x_{i+1}\in[a_{i+1},b_{i+1}],\dots,x_n\in[a_n,b_n]$, we define the function
> $$\begin{array}{cccc}F^P_{x_1\dots x_{i-1}x_{i+1}\dots x_n}:&[a_i,b_i]&\longrightarrow &\Bbb{R}^m\\ &x_i&\mapsto& F(x_1,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_n)\end{array}$$ which "fix" the coordinates of $F$ at $P$, except for $x_i$. Then, we say $F$ is *absolutely continuous on lines* (or, simply, ACL), if, for every parallelepiped $P\in \Omega$,
> $$F^P_{x_1\dots x_{i-1}x_{i+1}\dots x_n} \text{ is absolutely continuous for almost every "$n-1$-choice" as above.}$$

**What I want to prove, maybe throughout Proposition 1, is**

> **Proposition 2:** If $F:\Omega\subset \Bbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \Bbb{R}^m$ is ACL, then $\nabla F$ (or, partial derivatives) exists almost everywhere on $\Omega$.

"Almost everywhere" (:D) I've searched, books say "it's easy to see", "easy to prove", but I could not do it by myself. Can some one at least give me some insight of how to do it?

I really need the case where $n=m=2$. Fixing $x$ and looking to $F^R_x(y)=F(x,y)$, I've tried to use that, at those points in which $F^R_y$ is NOT absolutely continuous is a set of measure zero, Proposition 1 holds. And, then, to look to the points where $F_x^R$ is NOT differentiable (which again has measure zero) and finally to make the union (in $x$) of all these sets, hoping that this had still measure zero. Done this, I would have taken out from $R$ a set of measure zero. Doing the same for fixed $y$'s I would have reached the result. But my conjecture has prooved to be FALSE (in the sense that this set I'm looking at might NOT TO BE MEASURABLE), as we see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913801/suitable-non-countable-union-of-sets-with-measure-zero-is-still-a-set-of-measure/1913825#1913825).

THANK YOU, GUYS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trivial; requires only the definitons, Proposition 1 and Tonelli.

Suppose, just to simplify the typing, that $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ is ACL. Define $$f_y(x)=f(x,y).$$By definition, $f$ ACL says that almost every $f_y$ is AC, hence Proposition 1 shows that $f_y$ is differentiable almost everywhere. But the definition of $\partial f/\partial x$ says, in slightly unfortunate notation, that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=f_y'(x).$$

So: For almost every $y$, $\partial f/\partial x$ exists at $(x,y)$ for almost every $x$. Now Tonelli's Theorem shows that $\partial f/\partial x$ exists almost everywhere.

**Edit** Looking back at the question I see you're concerned about measurability, which I ignored above. This can't be a real problem... Ok, here's a kludge.

Say $E$ is the set of $y$ such that $f_y$ is not AC. Define $g(x,y)=0$ for $y\in E$, $f(x,y)$ for $y\notin E$. Since $\Bbb R\times E$ has measure zero it's enough to show that $\partial g/\partial x$ exists almost everywhere.

For $\delta>0$ define $$\omega_\delta g(x,y)=\sup_{0<s<t<\delta}\left|\frac{g(x+s,y)-g(x,y)}{s}-\frac{g(x+t,y)-g(x,y)}{t}\right|.$$Since every $g_y$ is continuous it's enough to take the sup over rational $s$ and $t$; hence $\omega_\delta g$ is measurable. The argument above shows that $\omega_{1/n}g\to0$ almost everywhere, and this shows that $\partial g/\partial x$ exists almost everywhere.

Comment: "By definition, $f $
 ACL says that every $f_y$ is AC." Not every, but ALMOST every, right?

Comment: Right - I didn't look closely at the definition, sorry. (|Absolutely continuous on lilnes" sounds like it's referring to every line...)

Comment: C. Ulrich: Really, maybe "absolutely continuous on almost every line" (ACAEL) sounds better, albeit it is a long long term 

Comment: @AndersonFelipeViveiros Just realized I didn't really answer your question. See edit.