# Homeomorphisms of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are partial-differentiable a.e.? ACL?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, absolute-continuity

I was wondering, is every homeomorphism between open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ necessarily (component-wise) [ACL](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914263/f-acl-implies-exists-nabla-f-almost-everywhere), or at least "partial-differentiable along coordinate directions" (or just along a given direction) almost everywhere?

Note: We recall absolute continuity implies differentiability almost-everywhere (cf. e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity)) for single-variable functions;
consequently ACL implies partial-differentiability (along a given, or finitely-many given, directions) ae.

Remark: Differentiability ae should apply in $n=1$.
Proof: A homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is necessarily monotone, hence by [Lebesgue's theorem](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/lebesgue-s-theorem-for-the-differentiability-of-monotone-fun)
it is differentiable ae.